# Creatures with Surge as Commander

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Is it possible to use a creature with a surge ability as my commander?
a creature such as [Tyrant of Valakut](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tyrant%20of%20Valakut)?

If so would this allow me to bypass the cost increase by using the surge ability, or would the surge cost increase as well?

I am new to commander so I am not fully aware of the comprehensive rules on creature abilities like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a creature with a surge ability as my commander?

Yes

Surge does not care about where your card is when you cast it, so it also works in command zone.

You still need to apply commander tax to the cost afterwards

> a creature such as Tyrant of Valakut?

No

I believe your commander should be a legendary creature, which Tyrant of Valakut is not.

Comment: Ah I was not aware that a creature had to be legendary to be commander... this pretty much answers my question thanks.

Comment: @ThunderToes See http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php

Comment: There are presently [no legendary creatures with surge](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3Asurge+t%3Alegendary&v=card&s=cname) in fact. :'(